# Simba ODBC Driver - Tableau+MongoDB - Can't view published Tableau dashboards in Tableau Server

Tags: mongodb, odbc, tableau-api, simba

I'm using Simba's ODBC driver for connecting Tableau to MongoDB.
I connected my workbook to MongoDB, developed my dashboard and everything went pretty smooth.
However, after I publish my workbook to Tableau server and try to open it, I get an error message:

"An unexpected error occurred. If you continue to receive this error please contact your Tableau Server Administrator.
Tableau Server encountered an error. Contact your Tableau Server Administrator.
Would you like to reset the view?"

[image]

Why can't I view this dashboard in Tableau Server?

Comment: Did the dashboard appear correctly in the preview pane of Tableau Desktop, during publication?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the Simba's ODBC driver on the machine that runs your Tableau Server.

Comment: The Tableau Server & Desktop are both installed on the same machine. The driver is installed on that machine.

Comment: As suggested below, make sure the driver bitness (32/64 bit) matches the bitness of your Tableau Server process. If you are using DSN, make sure it's defined as system DSN, visible to the user running Tableau Server.

Comment: @aseidlitz can we not define DSN at user level. can you please provide your inputs on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177453/tableau-linux-server-does-it-not-recognize-the-user-odbc-settings

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons which can bring this error.

1. Driver mismatch on server machine.
2. Data volume too much for server to handle (does it take too much time for the server to load and then show this err or does it show it quickly after hitting url?)
3. It could simply be that there was some error while publishing the dashboard try again.