# Tableau Linux server, does it not recognize the user ODBC settings

Tags: odbc, admin, unixodbc, tableau-api, settings

Connecting data source via ODBC driver to the tableau server seem to not work at a user level.

I have ***`odbc.ini`*** and ***`obdcinst.ini`*** files on the user home directory. **`$ODBCINI`** and **`$ODBCINSTINI`** Environment variables are set pointing to respective files.Tableau still fail to pick the data source.

Workbook published from the desktop is rendered only on placing the ***`odbc.ini`*** and ***`odbcinst.ini`*** into ***`/etc/`*** or tableau user directory (***`/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/`***).

Although it fixes the issue, there are multiple users on the system and we do not want to configure at a system level affecting all the users.

https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-17674 suggests to configure  `ODBCSYSINI` in *`/etc/systemd/system/tabsvc_0.service`*. The latest version of tableau (**`2018.3`**) seem to have the conf file at *`/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/.local/share/systemd/user/tabsvc_0.service`*. How can we configure it to use the settings for each user and restart this service?

Comment: Try moving the `~/odbc.ini` and `~/odbcinst.ini` to `~/.odbc.ini` and `~/.odbcinst.ini`.  You could also set `$ODBCINI` and `$ODBCINSTINI` to respectively target these files, which will usually cause the similar files in `/etc/` and other default locations to be ignored.  (This would all be done without touching `tabsvc_0.service`.)

Comment: Thanks @TallTed for the response. I did set the ENV variables $ODBCINI and $ODBCINSTINI respective to each file. Tableau server still did not recognize the data source name.

Comment: Did you try shifting the config files in the user's home directory from the un-dotted filenames to the dotted filenames? I know this seems silly. But it's part of [how unixODBC works](http://www.unixodbc.org/odbcinst.html). _"The system files are odbcinst.ini and odbc.ini (note no leading dot), and the user file is ~/.odbc.ini in each user's home directory (note leading dot)."_